# Iterating over character of vector string (C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer)

Tags: c++

I m trying to iterate over a vector of string, and over each character of the string:

But I get an error: C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.

```
In member function ‘int LetterStrings::sum(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)’:

error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
```

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class LetterStrings {
    public:
        int sum(vector <string> s) {
            int i, j = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for(i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
                for(j=0;j<s[i].length();j++) {
                    if(s[i][j] != "-") {
                        count ++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
};
```

Can someone please tell me, whats wrong with my code.

** I m really new to C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(s[i][j] != "-")
```

It should be:

```
if(s[i][j] != '-') // note the single quotes - double quotes denote a character string
```

Comment: Oh! That was too easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Now that [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968808/335858) has identified the problem in your statement, here is a modernized way to achieve the same result in a single line:

```
int count = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [](int p, string s) {
    return p + count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {return c != '-';});
});
```

The idea is to use C++11's lambdas to perform counting in two dimensions:

- `accumulate` goes through the vector one string at a time, and calls the top-level lambda
- `count_if` goes through your strings character-by-character, computing the number of non-dash characters.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/wDhFvA).